# How solve this recurrence: T(n) = 2t(n-1) - t(n-2) +5n +7

Tags: recursion

I am trying to solve the recurrence: T(n) = 2t(n-1) - t(n-2) +5n +7 but without success.

[image]

And from here I don't know how to continue?

Comment: My point is probably moot since the asker will probably not come back and I do not want to reopen a question that old, but I cannot see how this question is a duplicate except possibly to the answer [Guess & Prove](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2799/91753), an answer that is both powerful and illusive.

Answer (score -3):

According to your recurrence equation  2t(n-1) futher breakdown like 2[2t((n-1)-1)+t((n-1)-2)+5(n-1)+7] and for solution of this equation explore 
[recurrence equation solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316301/if-tn-tn-1-2tn-2)

Comment: This is not the same recurrence as the one considered in the linked question.